# Click event not firing for context menu when placed inside ItemsControl

Tags: wpf, itemscontrol, .net-4.6.1

I have a `ContextMenu`, which is defined as a part of `ItemsControl.ItemTemplate -> DataTemplate`. The problem is I can't get the `Click` event notification in the code behind. Below is simplified version of my code:

Models:

```
public class RunYear
{
    public RunYear(int year)
    {
        Year = year;
        Months = new Month[3];
    }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public Month[] Months { get; set; }
}

public class Month
{
    public int ColumnIndex { get; set; }
    public string MonthName { get; set; }
    // some other props
}
```

XAML Code behind:

```
    private ObservableCollection<RunYear> _years = new ObservableCollection<RunYear>();
    public ObservableCollection<RunYear> Years { get{return _years; } }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        GenerateData();
    }

    private void GenerateData()
    {
        for (int i = 2010; i < 2015; i++)
        {
            var runYear = new RunYear(i);
            runYear.Months[0] = new Month() { ColumnIndex = 0, MonthName = $"Jan {i}" };
            runYear.Months[1] = new Month() { ColumnIndex = 1, MonthName = $"Feb {i}" };
            runYear.Months[2] = new Month() { ColumnIndex = 2, MonthName = $"Mar {i}" };
            Years.Add(runYear);
        }
    }

    public void OnManageClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("manage");
    }

    public void OnDeleteClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("delete");
    }
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="SimplerOne.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SimplerOne"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>

    <ItemsControl Name="icYears" ItemsSource="{Binding Years}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="70" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="75"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Content="{Binding Year}" />

                    <ItemsControl Grid.Column="1" Name="icMonths" ItemsSource="{Binding Months}">
                        <ItemsControl.Resources>
                            <ContextMenu x:Key="ctxMenuFilingFrequency">
                                <MenuItem Header="Manage" Click="OnManageClicked" />
                                <MenuItem Header="Delete" Click="OnDeleteClicked" />
                            </ContextMenu>
                        </ItemsControl.Resources>
                        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <Grid >
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="75"></RowDefinition>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                </Grid>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                            <Style>
                                <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding ColumnIndex}" />
                            </Style>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Border BorderThickness="0.5" BorderBrush="Black">
                                    <StackPanel Background="White">
                                        <StackPanel.Style>
                                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type StackPanel}">
                                                <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource ctxMenuFilingFrequency}"></Setter>
                                            </Style>
                                        </StackPanel.Style>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding MonthName}"  Padding="2" Margin="2"></TextBlock>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </Border>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CallMethodAction` from `WPF`.

Just add `Microsoft.Expression.Interactions` and `System.Windows.Interactivity` to your project.

[image]

#### XAML Code

```
<ItemsControl.Resources>
    <ContextMenu x:Key="ctxMenuFilingFrequency">
        <!--<MenuItem Header="Manage" Click="OnManageClicked" />-->
        <MenuItem Header="Manage">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                    <ei:CallMethodAction MethodName="ManageClicked" TargetObject="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=local:MainWindow}}" />
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </MenuItem>
    </ContextMenu>
</ItemsControl.Resources>
```

Use it in your `XAML` code.

#### C# Code behind (MainWindow.cs)

```
public void ManageClicked()
{
    //I get fired from XAML
}
```

Define a method in code behind. It musst me `public void` without any parameter!

Comment: Thank-you but I couldn't find those assemblies listed. Anyways, I worked around the problem by adding button and using the click event instead of the context menu.

Comment: Just install the Blend.SDK with the "Visual Studio Updater" ☝️